# Solfège (do re mi fa sol la si do) sung by human voice

Tags: data-request, music, audio

I am looking for a collection of voice files for individual piano notes.

Any audio format, for instance ogg or mp3.

Needs to be freely reusable, and reasonably accurate.

Having several different versions of each file (sung by different humans) would be wonderful, but a single voice is OK too.

Comment: Related question on [softwarerecs.se]: [Music software with human voice as the tone](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10330/60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to make **midi** files, then you can use a vocal sound font (like choir sound fonts) to play that midi file. You can find a collection of choir sound fonts [here](http://www.freedrumkits.net/sound-fonts/7-choirs?start=10).

Here are the steps:

1. Make a midi file with the software of your choice (I don't exactly know how to do that, so can't recommend any, but maybe you can try **Aria Maestosa**)
2. Download a choir sound font. Or you can just Google for it.
3. Install VLC media player and then install the font you downloaded. An instruction can be found [here](http://adamrehn.com/articles/miscellaneous/playing-midi-soundfonts).
4. Play the midi file.