# Who else sings Do, Re, mi?

Tags: data-request, music

I'm looking for human voices singing do, re, me etc. for sampling. Each sample is then asscociated with a particular MIDI key. My challenge is to find more (public) recordings to sample. I don't need the whole Rogers & Hammerstein number (thats copyright anyway), just someone singing the solfege scale.

Julie Andrews in "Sound Of Music" is a starting point, although backing music can be heard in some samples. I have also found Harry Secombe, in the movie "Sunstruck". Does anyone know of other recordings or performances?

Edit: A similar question was asked before [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/solf%C3%A8ge-do-re-mi-fa-sol-la-si-do-sung-by-human-voice).  That request was [from my understanding] covering general choir sounds, like "ooh" and "aaah" available in a choir sound font. I'm looking for the **specific** "Do Re Mi" etc.

The idea being: when playing a MIDI file, you hear a voice intoning the name of the note, in the right key. Primary use is an aide in learning the musical scale.

Comment: Welcome to Open Data! Is your question different from http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/solf%C3%A8ge-do-re-mi-fa-sol-la-si-do-sung-by-human-voice? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old Soviet cartoon that includes several instances of the notes being sung in order. The voice is often different for each note, however, and the pronunciation is also distinct by virtue of being sung in Russian. But perhaps useful nonetheless?

[DoReMi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN5saJf5Wa0)

Comment: Nice one. There seems to be a piano in the background, but I could make a similar complaint for Julie Andrews. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The link is dead unfortunately.